# Autocomplete 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using autocomplete for my panel and get stuck with queries. I'm getting products from prestashop database and do the following (example with 1 query):

```
$return_arr = array();

if ($ps_DB_con) {
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT ps_product.id_product
  AS id_product, ps_product.id_manufacturer
  AS producent_id, ps_manufacturer.name
  AS producent, ps_product_shop.price
  AS cena, ps_product_shop.active
  FROM ps_product
  LEFT JOIN ps_product_shop ON ps_product.id_product=ps_product_shop.id_product
  LEFT JOIN ps_manufacturer ON ps_product.id_manufacturer=ps_manufacturer.id_manufacturer
  WHERE ps_product.id_product LIKE :term";
$result = $ps_DB_con->prepare($query);
$result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
$result->execute();

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return_arr[] = array('id_product' => $row['id_product'], 'producent' => $row['producent'], 'label' => "{$row['id_product']}");
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

I would like to put 2nd query to this and join results to return_arr[] in while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ps_feature_value_lang.value as szerokosc from ps_feature_value_lang
        left join ps_feature_product on ps_feature_value_lang.id_feature_value= ps_feature_product.id_feature_value
        left join ps_feature_lang on ps_feature_product.id_feature=ps_feature_lang.id_feature
        where ps_feature_product.id_product LIKE :term and ps_feature_product.id_feature='17'

Select ps_feature_value_lang.value as profil from ps_feature_value_lang
        left join ps_feature_product on ps_feature_value_lang.id_feature_value= ps_feature_product.id_feature_value
        left join ps_feature_lang on ps_feature_product.id_feature=ps_feature_lang.id_feature
        where ps_feature_product.id_product LIKE :term and ps_feature_product.id_feature=18
```

How can I join those queries into one?